# Rename a item on a list and go to another item with next and prev buttons, but keep the renamed items in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a list:

```
self._filenames = [
            "image1.png",
            "image2.png",
            "image3.png",
            "image4.png",
            "image5.png",
            "image6.png",
        ]
```

And a new desired filename:

```
def createNewFilename(self):
    self._newFilename = "New filename"
```

And PyQt5 buttons and a label:

[image]

If I:

- push **Next** to go to **image2.png**
- push **Rename** button

Then: How can I get the list item **image2.png** to be renamed as **New filename** and to stay in the list and to get updated into the label?

- When I keep pressing **Previous** or **Next** buttons, I should be able to rename other filenames as well, and by clicking, go through the updated filenames in the list.

Here's the short code for the whole thing:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._current_index = 0
        self._filenames = []
        self._newFilename = ""
        self._createNewFilename = ""

        self.previous_button = QPushButton("Previous")
        self.next_button = QPushButton("Next")
        self.rename_button = QPushButton("Rename")
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label2 = QLabel()

        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.previous_button, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.next_button, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.rename_button, 0, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.label2, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0, 1, 3)

        self.previous_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_previous)
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_next)
        self.rename_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_rename)

        self._update_button_status(False, True)

        self.load_files()

    def load_files(self):
        self._filenames = [
            "image1.png",
            "image2.png",
            "image3.png",
            "image4.png",
            "image5.png",
            "image6.png",
        ]
        self.current_index = 0

    def handle_next(self):
        self.current_index += 1

    def handle_previous(self):
        self.current_index -= 1
    @property
    def current_index(self):
        return self._current_index

    @current_index.setter
    def current_index(self, index):
        if index <= 0:
            self._update_button_status(False, True)
        elif index >= (len(self._filenames) - 1):
            self._update_button_status(True, False)
        else:
            self._update_button_status(True, True)

        if 0 <= index < len(self._filenames):
            self._current_index = index
            filename = self._filenames[self._current_index]
            pixmap = QPixmap(filename)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.label2.setText(filename)

    def _update_button_status(self, previous_enable, next_enable):
        self.previous_button.setEnabled(previous_enable)
        self.next_button.setEnabled(next_enable)

    def createNewFilename(self):
        self._newFilename = "New filename"

    def handle_rename(self, index):
        newFilename = self._newFilename
        print(newFilename) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. When should the second item be renamed? As a response to what?

Comment: @musicamante Alright. How about now, I edited it a bit.

Comment: You never change anything in your list in your "hadle_rename" funktion - so _why should anything change?_

Comment: You need to replace the item in `self._filenames[self._current_index]` with your new name ... until you do nothing changes in the list!

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks for the clue! I'll try something with my limited skills :)

Comment: Why not just add a `self._filenames[self.current_index] = newFilename` and a `self.label2.setText(newFilename)` in your `handle_rename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not clear.
Do you want to rename the actual file on your compute or just the list in python ?

for the last, you can do :

```
    def handle_rename(self):
        self.createNewFilename()
        self._filenames[self._current_index] = self._newFilename
        self.current_index = self._current_index
```

for the first, assuming `self._filenames` contain path you can do this :

```
import os

    def handle_rename(self):
        self.createNewFilename()
        try:
            os.rename(self._filenames[self._current_index], self._newFilename)
        except OSError:
            pass
        else:
            self._filenames[self._current_index] = self._newFilename
            self.current_index = self._current_index
```

the last code require a bit of modification if the new filename isn't a path.

Comment: eventually yes, on my computer - but also to display the current and changed filenames in a label. I think I can handle the renaming on computer part.

Comment: if so, just put the first handle_rename code and it should work !

Comment: Oh my, for some reason if the createNewFilename() is more complicated, this stops to work, very weird....       -   https://images.manujarvinen.com/python_problem.png     -     Even though I keep the handle_rename identical :/ What could be the reason?

Comment: can you provide the new createNewFilename() code in text format ?

Comment: you need to remove the line `return newFilename`

Comment: ooooh, interesting - sadly I already started to structure everything in other ways... :/

Comment: here's the code if you still bother to use it: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/manujarvinen/61cd45fa74a31af06dddaac4ee3176a2/raw/31fd10f98b1773fdfe195ffba20c12c84d41b47e/snippet.py